# Sublist extraction

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a set of observations made by 5 different sensors a, b, c, d, e at various times.

The observations may have an integer value, or "x" if the observation is incomplete.

A typical set of observations would look like:

```
lis = {{a,3},{b,4},{b,x},{c,x},{d,1},{d,2},{e,3}}
```

I wish to discard a sensor's incomplete results in the case it has complete results, in other words operating on {{b,4},{b,x}} would give {{b,4}}. In the event the same sensor has provided 2 different (completed) results, I wish to keep both, i.e. operating on {{d,1},{d,2}} would give {{d,1},{d,2}}.

The goal is to get the following from lis:

```
{{a,3},{b,4},{c,x},{d,1},{d,2},{e,3}}
```

I will study "Cases" some more.

Comment: Why do you want to keep `{c,x}` while you discard `{b,x}`?

Comment: Not OP, but @corey979 `{c, x}` is the only entry that starts with `c`, while `{b, x}` is not the only entry with `b`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Solution

```
Catenate[GatherBy[Sort@lis, First] //. {a__, {_, x}, b___} :> {a, b}]
```

> `{{a, 3}, {b, 4}, {c, x}, {d, 1}, {d, 2}, {e, 3}}`

## Explanation

```
Sort@lis
```

Sort the list in canonical order, so that lists with a number in second position appear before lists with `x` in second position.

```
GatherBy[ ... , First]
```

Group the resulting list according to the first element.

```
... //. {a__, {_, x}, b___} :> {a, b}
```

Delete all `{_, x}` that appear in second position or later.

```
Catenate[ ... ]
```

Join the lists again.

If you want the output to be grouped by sensor, delete `Catenate[]`.

Comment: Awesome.  I am learning more from the solution than from the question :)

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{a, 3}, {b, 4}, {b, x}, {c, x}, {d, 1}, {d, 2}, {e, 3}};
```

Using `Delete` and `SequencePosition`

```
f = 
 With[{s = Sort @ #}, 
    Delete[List @* Last /@ SequencePosition[s, {{a_, _}, {a_, x}}]] @ s] &;

f @ list
```

{{a, 3}, {b, 4}, {c, x}, {d, 1}, {d, 2}, {e, 3}}

A more complicated example

```
list = 
 {{a, 3}, {b, 4}, {b, x}, {c, x}, {d, 1}, {d, 2}, {e, 3}, {b, 4}, 
  {b, x}, {z, x}, {z, 4}};

f @ list
```

{{a, 3}, {b, 4}, {b, 4}, {c, x}, {d, 1}, {d, 2}, {e, 3}, {z, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
lis = {{a, 3}, {b, 4}, {b, x}, {c, x}, {d, 1}, {d, 2}, {e, 3}};

First@ReplaceList[lis, {a__, {_, x}, b__} :> {a, b}]

(*{{a, 3}, {b, 4}, {c, x}, {d, 1}, {d, 2}, {e, 3}}*)
```